# Вывод массива на экран

Tags: php

Пробовал по разному на экран выходит куча "array", во общем добавляю в массив с помощью цикла:

```
> $idd = array(); // пустой массив
> while($a = mysql_fetch_array($b)) {
>                 $idd[$i]['id']=$a['id']; //добавляю в
> массив id из БД
>             
>                 $i++; }
```

вывод на экран тестирую так:

```
> for($q=0; $q < count($idd); $q++)    
> { 
>      echo  $idd[$q].'<br/>';        }
```

получаю на экран куча "array"
А хотелось бы увидеть содержимое, а как это еще по другому сделать, подскажите?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Множно придумать много вариантов.

Например:

```
/* Выведет:
 *    id => 1,<br />
 *    id => 2,<br />
 */
foreach($idd as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key => $value, ";
    }    
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Или

```
/* Выведет, правда с немного другим форматированием:
 *   array (0 => array ('id' => 1,),
 *          1 => array ('id' => 2,),
 *          2 => array ('id' => 3,),)
 */
var_export($idd);
```

Или, если PHP достаточно свеж:

```
// Выведет, если не путаю, «[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}]»
echo json_encode($idd);
```

Comment: спасибо, но на экран выходит:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
        )
и т.д.
хотелось бы 
10
21
22
и т.д. как таково ответа достичь)

Comment: Спасибо, достиг результата:)

Answer (score 4):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($idd);
```

или

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($idd);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = array (
    "Ключ 1 (уровень 1)" => array ( // Значение 1 (уровень 1)
        "Ключ 1 (уровень 2)" => "Значение 1 (уровень 2)",
        "Ключ 2 (уровень 2)" => "Значение 2 (уровень 2)",
        "Ключ 3 (уровень 2)" => "Значение 3 (уровень 2)",
    ),
    "Ключ 2 (уровень 1)" => array ( // Значение 2 (уровень 1)
        "Ключ 1 (уровень 2)" => "Значение 1 (уровень 2)",
        "Ключ 2 (уровень 2)" => "Значение 2 (уровень 2)",
        "Ключ 3 (уровень 2)" => "Значение 3 (уровень 2)",
    ),
    "Ключ 3 (уровень 1)" => array ( // Значение 2 (уровень 1)
        "Ключ 1 (уровень 2)" => "Значение 1 (уровень 2)",
        "Ключ 2 (уровень 2)" => "Значение 2 (уровень 2)",
        "Ключ 3 (уровень 2)" => "Значение 3 (уровень 2)",
    ),
);
while ( current ($list)) {
    $key1 = key ($list);
    echo "- " . $key1 . "<br><br>";
        while ( current ($list[$key1])) {
            $key2 = key ($list[$key1]);
            $value = current ($list[$key1]);
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- " . $key2 . " => " . $value . "<br>";
            next ($list[$key1]);
        }
    echo "<br>";
    next ($list);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($n1 as $value) 
echo "$value";
```

Массив будет выведен без индекса!